# How to print the text in a paragraph element using Mojolicious

Tags: html, perl, mojolicious

```
 use strict;
 use warnings;
 use feature 'say';

 use Mojo;

 my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new;

 my $array = $ua->get('http://blogs.perl.org/')->res->dom->find('div > p ')->map('text')->join("\n");

 my @arr = split("\n",$array);
 print "\n$arr[0]\n";
```

When I run this code I get the following output

> lets you write your Perl 6 code using Roman numerals:

But I want output as:

> perl6-slang-roman lets you write your Perl 6 code using Roman numerals:

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The `text` method will fetch only the text nodes *immediately within* a node. To fetch all descendant text nodes you need to use `all_text`
- It is also rather ugly to use `join` and then `split` again to separate the elements into a list. The `find` method returns a `Mojo::Collection` object which can be indexed directly
- And it's as well to confine the selected `div` to one with the required class

Like this

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Mojo;

my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new;

my $collection = $ua->get('http://blogs.perl.org/')->res->dom->find('div.entry-body > p ');

say $collection->[0]->all_text;
```

### output

```
perl6-slang-roman lets you write your Perl 6 code using Roman numerals:
```

Comment: thank u sir . How I display all contents . When I am using                      [say $collection->all_text;  ]The following error has occur                              [ Can't locate object method "all_text" via package "Mojo::Collection"]   What I do